# PayPal website payments pro TLS

Tags: ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn, tls1.2

I am currently using PayPal IPN and PDT for my site using SSL.

I now want to switch my server to TLS but want to know if this will cause any issues with the PayPal setup I have? My guess is that it should all work OK, but want to know if anyone has had any experience with this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes TLS will work. Actually due to data security standard changes by the Payment Card Industry (PCI) Security Standards Council, you will be required to use TLS soon. Here is some more information on those changes but the live endpoints will be upgraded to require these security changes as of June 2016.

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913&expand=true&locale=en_US

Comment: Ah OK so I can upgrade to TLS and IPN and PDT will work regardless?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you review the link I provided because I believe TLS 1.2 is the minimum requirement.